# TYPO3 FLUID conditions while looping array

Tags: html, arrays, typo3, fluid

I have an array which contains a list of names. In the front end, this has to be listed in a listed way. Using the `<ul> and <li>` tags.

Half of the list should be displayed under one `<ul>` tag and the other half under another `<ul>` tag.

like this:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Now the problem is in FLUID I did not find a way to end the `<ul>` tags when the array loops half of the elements.

I want to do something like this

```
<f:for each="{my_array}" as="item">
<li>{item}</li>
<!-- if condition where count=(my_array%2) then use </ul><ul>-->
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should get the id in PHP for the element in the middle and then you can use a simple if, like this:

It is a bit extended version of `f:for`. Here you can check the `iteration` property. When you use the iteration.index it is the current index of elements. However an elementLimit you have to set.

It is several properties for `iteration` : isFirst,isLast, isEven, isOdd, total, cycle, index.

[Here is an article about it.](http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/extensions/fluid/fluid-dokumentation.html)

***UPDATED example:***

```
<f:for each="{my_array}" as="item" iteration="itemIterator">
    <li>{item}</li>
    <f:if condition="{itemIterator.index} = {elementLimit}">
        </ul><ul>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a quick fix. Thanks :) 
But I was wondering, cant we like have a counter variable in FLUID ?  Just a thought, would be nice, if there is one

Comment: Very well, my example is updated. It is a solution for a counter, itration.index or iteration.cycle (index from 0 and cycle from 1) but you still need to declare what does it mean "half" for the condition. However maybe it is a more suitable solution for you :-)

Comment: Was it useful, or do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Forgot to check it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The only problem is when there is an odd amount of menu entries.

```html
<f:for each="{my_array}" as="item" iteration="itemIterator">
    <ul>
        <li>{item}</li>
        <f:if condition="{itemIterator.iterator}%({itemIterator.total}/2) == 0">
            </ul><ul>
        </f:if>
    </ul>
</f:for>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, returns `#1244201848: A boolean expression has more than tree parts`